# Getting the count of a Filtered Result in a template on Django

Tags: django

Im trying to access a related model on the template like this:

```
course.course_set.all.0.section_set.all.0.student_assignation.count
```

The problem is that I would like to count all the student assignations which have an `active = True` property.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
course.course_set.all.0.section_set.all.0.student_assignation(active=True).count
```

How can I accomplish this on the django template?

Answer (score 1):

Django templates are note meant for such complex queries. 
There are a few ways you can handle this

One, create a custom [django template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)

Two, create a class method which would provide this info.

Example

```
class Course:
    ...
    def sutdent_assign_count(self):
        #Your query goes here..
```

Comment: Creating a custom template filter to just add the `.filter(active=true)` should also work.

Comment: Sure, but that would lead to separation of logic, and more buggy code, unless this is a repetitive pattern

Comment: Another option is to have a all_active() method on a custom manager. But I think we need to know more about what he's trying to do.

Comment: I though about the manager. But the problem is that I don't always want to get the filter to be applied. if I create the `student_assign_count(self):`as karthikr suggested, how do I create the query in order to filter based on the current queryset?

Comment: I dont think you need it per queryset. You need it per object. Example: `course.course_set.first().section_set.first().student_assignation(active=True).count()` - Ofcourse, this might need tweaks, but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

You have far too much logic in the template. Create a method on one of your model classes that actually returns the number you want; I'd propose one, but it's too unclear what you're doing (why the `.all.0`, aren't the other results important? Why course.course_set, is that a many to many to itself?). What are your models like?

How would you describe what you are displaying in English? That probably gives a hint to what kind of method you should create.